# Select field value with different placed possible combinations

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to select value of field in different possible combination of containing item1,2,3,4,5. It doesn't matter where the item is placed, but each field must contain each item.

```
id_num    field1       field2   field3   field4   field5
  1        item1       item2    item3    item4     item5   > true
  2        item3       item3    item3    item4     item5   > false
  3        item2       item1    item3    item4     item5   > true
  4        item5       item4    item3    item2     item1   > true
  5        item1       item1    item3    item4     item5   > false
  6        item2       item2    item4    item4     item5   > false
```

I tried using regular query `SELECT * from tb_name where field1=item1 AND field2=item2 etc...` it must be consuming very much OR OR AND OR, it must be not very efficient.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`field`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)  function to make your query slightly simpler than just a bunch of `and`s and `or`s:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tb_name
WHERE  FIELD ('item1', field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) > 0 AND
       FIELD ('item2', field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) > 0 AND
       FIELD ('item3', field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) > 0 AND
       FIELD ('item4', field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) > 0 AND
       FIELD ('item5', field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) > 0
```

Comment: wow, I dont know mysql have such function, thank you verymuch for quick and helpfull reply!

Answer (score 2):

Try using concat and like

```
select concat(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) as checkstring,item_id from table where
concat(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) like '%item1%'
and concat(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) like '%item2%'
and concat(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) like '%item3%'
and concat(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) like '%item4%'
and concat(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) like '%item5%'
```

Updated.

Comment: Hello I don't know it appear something went wrong or mysql 4 not supported it display error :

SELECT CONCAT(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) checkstring,* FROM tb_check WHERE checkstring LIKE '%item1%'

Result :
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from tb_check where checkstring LIKE '%item1%'' at line 1

Comment: very nice! now I can implement search function too, thanks steve!